# is it possible to play video with unity webgl on mobile devices

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

by using the WebglMovieTexture plugin from unity, I managed to play video on my webgl build on RawImage canvas

But no matter what I try, on mobile device I only get a gray screen.
Is it possible at all?

I could not find any result on google related to that

Comment: Recommend you try [remote debugging](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging?hl=en) and checking for any errors in the device browser's console. It's possible that a file or library failed to load for some reason, but that's hard to troubleshoot without more info.

Comment: the current way of displaying webgl video is only a temporary solution until unity manage to make MovieTexture work on webgl.

I have never seen any webgl build with video on mobile yet.
I also have never find any result on google about the possibility.

It look like to few people are crazy enough like me to make webgl game for mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

As of Unity 5.3.5 (the current version when I am writing this answer), WebGL builds do not support mobile devices.

If anything in a WebGL build works on a mobile device, you're just getting lucky.

Comment: our game run perfectly well in most mobile device.
it is not luck but experience.

Comment: My game does not work in WebGL on my iPhone. You got lucky. I even get a popup saying "WebGL builds do not support mobile devices."

Comment: this is just a warning, you can remove it in the index.html file generated by the build
Also, for apple product data caching make a lot of trouble and try to only allocate 256 mo of ram.
chrome can take up to 512 but is unstable.
also avoid all runtime code generation like reflection.
this is one of the many thing to do in order to have webgl builds work on mobile devices

Comment: It's not *supported*. The company making the engine doesn't care whether it works or not.

Comment: the question is not about the support but if someone managed to do it.
I know it is not supported and currently our whole project is in the not supported and should not work at all area. Webgl video is jsut one of the many thing we had to outcome. Chances are we are going to make our own codec

Comment: Doing unsupported stuff with an engine in a mission-critical app is very bad practice. Later versions of the engine can break what you have working, potentially leaving you with no way to upgrade other issues in your app.

Comment: we have been extra carefull on that side
The only exeption so far are video and we use not assets from unity asset store